# MySQL 1054 error: "Unknown column 'currency' in 'field list'"

Tags: mysql, database

I'm trying to create a database, but I have a hard time trying to solve the 1054 error. Could you please help me to solve this error and understand how to solve this type of issues?

here is the code:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `rooms` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `type` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `price` double DEFAULT NULL,
  `currency` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `country` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `image` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `review` text,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=5 ;

--
-- --------------------------------------------------------


INSERT INTO `rooms` (`id`, `name`, `type`, `price`, `currency`, `country`, `image`, `review`) VALUES
(1, 'Camera single', '1 persoana', 50, 'euro', 'Taiwan', 'Images/Rooms/Camera single superior (3 stele).jpg', 'Calatoriti singur, in interes de afaceri sau pentru a vizita diverse obiective turistice din zona? Atunci camera Superior Single este ideala pentru dvs! Aici veti gasi confortul de care aveti nevoie si un mic dejun copios, totul la preturi avantajoase!'')'),
(2, 'Camera twin', '2 persoane', 100, 'euro', 'Taiwan', 'Images/Rooms/camera twin.jpg', 'Aveti posibilitatea de a opta pentru paturi separate sau apropiate, in functie de cum doriti. De asemenea, baia cu vana, in loc de dus, reprezinta o optiune in plus pentru a va relaxa. Micul dejun pentru 2 persoane este inclus in pret!'')'),
(3, 'Camera Junior Suite', '4 persoane', 200, 'euro', 'Taiwan', 'Images/Rooms/camera junior suite.jpg', 'Cautati confort sporit? Atunci va recomandam sa alegeti acest tip de Suita, formata din doua camere separate: un dormitor cu un pat matrimonial si un living, camere ce se completeaza armonios. Micul dejun pentru 2 persoane este inclus in pret!'')'),
(4, 'Camera Senior Suite', '2 persoane', 200, 'euro', 'Taiwan', 'Images/Rooms/camera senior suite.jpg', 'Fiecare astfel de Suita este compusa din doua camere spatioase separate de un hol: un dormitor cu un pat matrimonial si un living generos. Micul dejun pentru 2 persoane este inclus in pret!'')'),
(5, 'Camera Budget Single', '1 persoana', 25, 'euro', 'Taiwan', 'Images/Rooms/camera buget single.jpg', 'Calatoriti cu un buget redus? Acum aveti posibilitatea de a va caza in hotelul nostru la conditii asemanatoare celor de 3* si la tarife convenabile pentru dumneavoastra! Micul dejun este inclus!'')'),
(6, 'Camera Budget Twin', '2 persoane', 50, 'euro', 'Taiwan', 'Images/Rooms/camera buget twin.jpg', 'Dacã dispuneţi de un buget redus, acest tip de camerã cu micul dejun inclus pentru 2 persoane şi condiţii asemãnãtoare celor de 3*, reprezintã soluţia pentru dumneavoastrã!'')');
```

Answer (score 1):

Did you recently add currency to the script? If so try dropping the table and execute the CREATE TABLE function again. Because it checks if the table exists, if it does, it doesn't execute the CREATE TABLE. Or you could add the column for currency using ALTER TABLE.

```sql
ALTER TABLE rooms
ADD currency varchar(255);
```

Comment: Thank you for your help, but now I have another error...


#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '--CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `rooms` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
' at line 4

Can you help me with this one too, please?

Comment: Nevermind, I found out.. It was a typo... Thanks for helping me a lot. :)